# Cloudbuild CI/CD cloudbuild.yaml issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am fairly new to using cloud build and am having problems with my cloudbuild.yaml file

cloudbuild.yaml

```
 steps:
  # Install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']
  # Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['run']
  # Deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
    args: ['deploy']
```

This code results in the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/deploy'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

So I switched it up and tried this code however this also results in an error.

```
steps:
  # Install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']
  # Build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['run']
  # Deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/project_id/image', '.']
  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project_id/image']
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
    - 'run'
    - 'deploy'
    - 'phase-2'
    - '--image'
    - 'gcr.io/project_id/image'
    - '--region'
    - 'europe-west2'
    - '--platform'
    - 'managed'
  images:
  - 'gcr.io/project_id/image'.
```

Here is the error:

```
Failed to trigger build: failed unmarshalling build config api/cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 26: did not find expected '-' indicator
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. I don't really understand the cloud build situation and have been manually creating docker images and uploading and deploying them via cloud run but it is getting time consuming to be doing 7/8 times a day.

Comment: `images` should be at the root level

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the advice, what do you mean by the root level? I have tried various variations of moving the indentation of images, adding a '-' indicator yet none still work. [link](https://i.gyazo.com/909ac782ca4567e84c9fd5fce19e23da.png)

Comment: Look here, the steps and images are at the same level: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#structure_of_a_build_config_file